# Need some help setting up Typescript and Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, typescript

I am quite New to typescript and I have tried to set up a typescript Project in Visual studio 2015 as HTML Application With Typescript. My problem is how to import or Reference highcharts without errors. I need a short description on how to set up the easist highchart in my typescript file. The description should explain from the start

1) creating the Project, and adding highchart (npm, tsd...) to the Project,

2) setting up the index.html file and app.ts (or the name of Your typescript file),

3) adding References in the html file and app.ts, especially in app.ts where you set import or References, like using import statement or

```
< reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />

< reference path="typings/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts" />
```

4) Set require statements and put into a variable
(I can't get this code to work ... Please use Your way to do this

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');

// Load module after Highcharts is loaded
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', { /*Highcharts options*/ });
```

5) Finally you render the highchart either in app.ts or by using the id in the index.html file

```
 <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

I hope somebody can help me out here. I could of course have done all this in index.html but I want to make use of the debugging possibilities in typescript.

Comment: Why you cannot get this code to work? What errors do you have?